# I'm looking to use Visual Studio to write and compile using the open source version of Qt4

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt

Does anyone have details in setting up Qt4 in Visual Studio 2008? Links to other resources would be appreciated as well.

I already know that the commercial version of Qt has applications to this end. I also realize that I'll probably need to compile from source as the installer for the open source does not support Visual Studio and installs Cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's even simpler now with QT4, you no longer need the patch. Basically you just need to supply "-spec win32-msvc2008" to configure.
There are detailed instructions here http://tom.paschenda.org/blog/?p=28

The visual studio add-in is also open-source and available.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's been done with Visual Studio 2005:
http://wiki.qgis.org/qgiswiki/Building_QT_4_with_Visual_C%2B%2B_2005

I'd imagine it would work with Visual Studio 2008, even if it requires some changes.

Comment: That info is out of date with qt4, you don't needthe patch anymore